# Java String Construction using Literal and new keyword

Tags: java, string

```
    public class Example{  
         public static void main(String args[]){  
               String s1=new String("name");
               String s2="name";
               System.out.println(s1==s2);  
    }}
```

Why does the above code return `false`? When a new string "name" is created it's created in the string constant pool as well as the heap. Next when the other string is created using the literal "name", should it not refer to the same object created int heap, as the literal "name" already exist in String Constant Pool?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/513839/261142

Comment: `new` always creates a new object. A new object is only the same as itself.

Comment: as this happens at compile time, no. You just force a new `String` with `new String`.

Comment: The String Literal Pool only contains String Literals, not new Strings you create.

Answer (score 2):

`new` always creates a new instance... thus circumventing all caching and pooling. So `new String("name")` will create a new string object containing the string `"name"`.

The string `"name"`, however is already generated and placed in the pool when the literal `"name"` is found. Thus even before `new` is called.

For the same reason you should always do:

```
Long.valueOf(42L);
```

instead of

```
new Long(42L);
```

Because `new` is guaranteed to return a new instance. There is no way around that.

Comment: in the question, the `new String` occurs first. Why isn't the String created there used in the next life?

Comment: @bradimus It is not created first... Because before the creation of new String(...) already the literal has been created.

Comment: Because first it occures in `"name"` inside `new String("name")`. Or if you want seriouse answer strings that will be in constant pool is determined at compail time.

Comment: Good. Now that we have established that, add it to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, when you say `new`, you are guaranteed to get a new object. The instance behind the literal "name" is in the constant pool and it's accessed by the constructor, copied, and returned from your `new` expression.